# Continously generating a random number if a button is clicked and stop when not clicked

Tags: android

I Want to generate a Random Numbers between 1 and 5 continously when button is clicked and want to stop this function when stop button is clicked...

What Should I Do Now with these toggle button on Checked Change Listener in order to achieve this....

```
toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {      
          }
        });
```

Comment: run a loop on start button click and stop it on stop button click it's so simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do code like this:**

1. Create a class level variable:

   ```
       boolean is generating=false;
   ```
2. Now on click of start button:

   ```
      startButton.setOnClickListener(.....
          onClick() {
                 isGenerating=true;
                 generateRandomNumber();
          }
      });
   ```
3. Now on click of stop button:

   ```
     stopButton.setOnClickListener(.....
          onClick() {
                 isGenerating=false;

          }
     });
   ```
4. Create a method:

   ```
      public void generateRandomNumber () 
     {
             while(isGenerating)
             {
                    Random rand = new Random(); 
                    int n = rand.nextInt(5) + 1;
                    //Here n is random number.
             }
     }
   ```

Thanks and happy coding.